# Why BAR is used in Postgresql WHILE loop?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

Im going through a tutorial and trying to solve a task but I saw that they have used `BAR` in the while loop and i just want to know what is the perpuse of it in the loop!

there is a table with 4 columns , Bike_id, type, size and available. for going throught this table they have used a while loop like this:

```
echo "$AVAILABLE_BIKES" | while read BIKE_ID BAR TYPE BAR SIZE
  do 
  echo "$BIKE_ID $TYPE $SIZE"
  done
```

Is it wrong if I just write it without `BAR`, like so:

```
echo "$AVAILABLE_BIKES" | while read BIKE_ID TYPE SIZE
  do 
  echo "$BIKE_ID $TYPE $SIZE"
  done
```

What is the difference? and in genral what is `BAR` doing here?

Comment: The BAR variable probably holds the field separator character from the file.  Include example line from file and we can be more sure

Comment: This is not a question about PostgreSQL, but about the shell.